# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'length') - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, shopping-cart

I'm making a functional shopping cart website for a school project website using javascript, i use addtoCart() function to get product data from the product page, and a showCart() function to display cart in the shopping cart page. After using addtoCart() on one of the product's page, i opened the shopping cart page to check if the showCart() is working or not and nothing happen so i check the console and it said "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'length')".

Here are the code:

```
//here are the JS codes
var cart = new Array();

function addtoCart(x){
    var sach = x.parentElement.children;
    var name = sach[0].innerText;
    var prc = sach[2].children[0].innerText;
    var img = x.parentElement.previousElementSibling.children[0].src;

    var prd = new Array(img, name, prc);
    giohang.push(prd);
    sessionStorage.setItem("cart", JSON.stringify(cart));
    alert('Added!')
}

function showCart(){
    var gh = sessionStorage.getItem("cart");
    var cart = JSON.parse(gh);
    var info = "";
    for(let i = 0; i < cart.length; i++){
        info += '<tr>'+
                '    <td><img src="'+cart[i][0]+'" width="120px" height="150px"></td>'+
                '    <td>'+cart[i][1]+'</td>'+
                '    <td>'+cart[i][2]+'</td>'+
                '</tr>';
    }
    document.getElementById("showcart").innerHTML = info;
}
showCart();

//and some lines from the cart page 
<main>
     <div class="title">
    <h2>Cart</h2>
     </div>
     <div class="product-cart">
        <table>
             <tr>
                <th>Sản Phẩm</th>
                <th></th>
                <th>Đơn Giá</th>
              </tr>
          <tbody id="showcart"></tbody>
         </table>
      </div>
</main>

//and some lines from the product page 

<div class="col-2">
     <h1 class="title">name</h1>
     <h3 class="author_name">author</h3>
     <h4 class="price"><span>price</span>đ</h4>
     <div class="button" onclick="addtoCart(this)">Add to Cart</div>
     <h3>Some Infomation: <i class="fa fa-indent"></i></h3>
     <br>
     <p class="overview">text</p>
</div>
```

There might me a problem with the .push method and around the addtoCart() function. How can i fix it?

Comment: Have you console.logged the cart variable => JSON object, to make sure there is indeed information there before you try to work with an object that may be empty?

Answer (score 0):

If you read the error ->
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'length')`

What this is telling you is that JS is trying to read a property called `length`, but the variable your reading from is `null`.

Now looking at the code you have provided the only place your doing this is in your `showCart` function.  `for(let i = 0; i < cart.length; i++){`

Now the likely reason for this is that your session storage is currently empty (null).

`var gh = sessionStorage.getItem("cart")` if there is no cart this will be `null`, you then `JSON.parse(null)`, that returns `null`.

So to cope with an empty session storage cart, you could do ->

```
var gh = sessionStorage.getItem("cart");
var cart = JSON.parse(gh) || [];
```

The above will then make the cart be an empty array instead of null, if no session storage has yet been set.